# persist some data in Android phone in my case

Tags: android, performance

I am developing my Android app. I would like to programmatically persist some data in Android device, **even after my app is uninstalled, the data could still be kept persisted**.

I have read the [Android Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) document, I know I could persist my data in SD card, but user might remove SD card. So, is there any other place I could persist my data which won't be removed when my app is uninstalled?

Comment: you can maintain your own server for that.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to ensure local data to be kept after the app is uninstalled, other than the way you said with SD Card.

Consider syncing data to/from a server, in order to be unbound by these restrictions of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can maintain a remote server and fetch data from there after reinstall.

2) You can use [Data Backup](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html) services.